# Which hostnames do browsers display as punycode?

Tags: url, browser, punycode

When I visit the URL `http://gibts.überhaupt.nicht` (German for: does.not.exist.at.all), my browser (Chrome) internally converts this to punycode `http://gibts.xn--berhaupt-55a.nicht` because of the umlaut character `ü`, but it still displays it as `http://gibts.überhaupt.nicht` in the address bar.

But when I visit the URL `http://ᴅᴏᴇs.not.exist` which starts with three "latin letter small capital" characters, it is displayed as punycode `http://xn--s-h6lg5a.not.exist` in the address bar.

How do browsers decide whether or not to display punycode? I understand this is important to prevent homograph attacks with characters that look similar to an ASCII character but are different. Do browsers consider the similarity of characters in this decision? Or does it depend on the Unicode block from which the characters come?

Comment: A fascinating question, to which I feel I should know the answer. I don't know, though. I can guess that it has something to do with the different error cases (gibts.überhaupt.nicht.de returns 404, ᴅᴏᴇs.not.exist has no server). But I wonder: Why does this matter, given that both are error cases? What is the real problem?

Comment: BTW, this is extremely unlikely to be connected to homograph attacks. Those are mostly prevented by a set of rules that ensure that if you own a domain, only you can register a homograph lookalike. (All-ASCII attacks such as ibrn.com against ibm.com or phiIIips.com against phillips.com are still possible, but using different scripts is growing difficult nowadays.)

Comment: It has got nothing to do with 404, same behavior if you visit gibts.überhaupt.nicht. What's the problem? I just want to know.